# How do I know if a software is 64bit or 32bit (x64 or x32)

Tags: netbeans, java-8, java-me

I wanted to install J2ME and configure it with Netbeans. I followed two different tutorials word by word but somehow mine would give me many errors. After so much searching I realized that the **JDK**, **Netbeans** and **J2ME** must all be of the same level ie. all to be of **x32** or all to be of **x64**. Now, how do I know what level is each of them at? 
How do I know if NetBeans is x32 or x64, as well as JDK and J2ME?

I am using JDK 1.8, Netbeans 8.2, J2ME 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Netbeans** and **J2ME** just open them, then open the **Task Manager**. On the list of Apps, the version of the software is shown as shown below.

[image: Task Manager]

About **JDK**, Open your **C Drive** and look for the installation folder of your **JDK**. If it is installed in the **Program File** folder then it is **x64**, if it is in the **Program File(x86)** then it is **x32**.

Answer (score 2):

For Java, you can do java -version, and it'll tell you what version you have.

I did a quick look around for the other two but couldn't find anything immediately. However, if you search something like "check bit version for Netbeans/J2ME" then you might get it.

Another way to figure out would be based on your OS. Depending on how new/old it is, it might require certain bit version. You probably installed the correct one (or you should uninstall and re-install the correct one based on their respective installation guide), so you should know what bit version when you first installed.